# Creating a location based reminder: what to do with horizontal accuracy?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, core-location, cllocation

I'm creating a location-based reminder, `EKReminder`.

For the coordinates I'm using `CLGeocoder` to convert an address into a `CLLocation`.

When it comes to the reminder itself, I think that there are two factors involved that determine the 'area' (radius/circle) in which the reminder will fire.

1) the Horizontal accuracy of the `CLLocation`.
The docs describe the `horizontalAccuracy` property as "The radius of uncertainty for the location, measured in meters. (read-only)".

There's more good information about this in a previous question:
[What do horizontalAccuracy and verticalAccuracy of a CLLocation refer to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402503/what-do-horizontalaccuracy-and-verticalaccuracy-of-a-cllocation-refer-to)

As suggested in that answer, the `horizontalAccuracy` is 100m.

2) the `radius` property on the `EKStructuredLocation`. The discussion notes for this property read "To use the default radius, set this property to 0."

If I create a location-based reminder in the stock, Reminders app from Apple, it comes out with `radius = 0` and `horizontalAccuracy = 0`. So it's using the default 'reminder radius' (don't know what that is) with a value of `0` for the uncertainty in the horizontal location...

I want to avoid having two margins in my reminder. I think there are two options to achieve this:

a) use the default `radius` for the `EKStructuredLocation` by setting  it to `0` and change the result coming back from the `CLGeocoder` to have a `horizontalAccuracy` of 0m.

b) keep the `horizontalAccuracy` (100m, or different, depending on circumstance) from the `CLGeocoder` - but not use the default `radius` for the `EKStructuredLocation` and set it to something small, like 1m.

Thoughts? Am I understanding these APIs correctly?

- Will I get a 'double margin' if I use the returned `horizontalAccuracy` and the default value for `radius`?
- Does the `horizontalAccuracy` for the `CLLocation` object introduce a radius from the coordinate, or is it purely giving information about the uncertainty of the location?

Cheers

Comment: horizontalAccuracy is an estimate of the uncertainty in the location value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by *progmr*, `horizontalAccuracy` is purely an estimate of the uncertainty in the location.

To back this up, I did a couple of real-world tests where:

- I created a location-based reminder in the Reminders app, which has `radius = 0` but also reports `horizontalAccuracy = 0`.
- I created a reminder using the same location in my own code, setting `radius = 0`, but the return from `CLGeocoder` reporting `horizontalAccuracy = 100`

With each test, the reminders fired at exactly the same position. `horizontalAccuracy` is purely for information.