# CoreLocation current accuracy/range

Tags: ios, core-location

I am using CLLocationManager to continuously scan location updates. I am setting *desiredAccuracy* which I understand is a best case- the question is, is there a way to know what the *current* accuracy is?

Comment: Not sure if it answers your question, but there is `horizontalAccuracy` and `verticalAccuracy` on `CLLocation`.

Comment: Ahhhh, how did I miss those? Curious why horizontal and vertical accuracies are distinct values though, considering you can only set a single desiredAccuracy filter.

Comment: NM, found this post useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402503/what-do-horizontalaccuracy-and-verticalaccuracy-of-a-cllocation-refer-to. I (incorrectly) assumed vertical/horizontal referred to lat/long. verticalAccuracy apparently refers to altitudinal accuracy.

Comment: @Fönsi if you submit your comment in the form of an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get a location from the `CLLocationManager` you can read the effective accuracy using `horizontalAccuracy` and `verticalAccuracy` on `CLLocation`.